# Mail.app's rules are sending the wrong messages to AppleScript

Tags: applescript, rules, apple-mail

I have the following AppleScript triggered by a Mail.app rule:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        repeat with msg in theMessages
            set theText to subject of msg & return & content of msg & date sent of msg
            display dialog (theText)
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

If I select a message, right click and choose 'Apply Rules' it works properly. However, if the script is triggered by an incoming message, it seems to have a random message in theMessages.

Here is the rule:[image]

How do I get the right message?

I'm using High Sierra with Mail 11.2.

Comment: does the random message is the same every time the trigger occurs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, handling incoming messages with rules is an asynchronous process. When `on perform mail action` is called, the message is not yet completely updated. Only partial data is available immediately.

A possible workaround would be to add a `delay 1` into the script. This give Mail a second to finish updating the message. Here is what the script then looks like:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        repeat with msg in theMessages
            -- delay a bit of time for msg to load
            delay 1

            set theText to subject of msg & return & content of msg & date sent of msg

            — do other processing

        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

As your script will iterate over your mail, I expect that your messages are not sorted by date ... So when you run you script it will take the first element (and not the most recent)

---

Could you run Mail, then sort your email by date (with the most recent at top position) then quit and re-run Mail (to double-check that configuration was saved)

Then verify if your script works.

---

If you don't want to set the filter manually, according to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4900350), you may add at the following script to the beginning :

```
tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Date" of menu "Sort By" of menu item "Sort By" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of process "Mail"
```

to sort email by date before running your script in order to get the right message.

You may also take a look [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-rules-to-manage-your-inbox-mlhlp1017/mac), [here](https://9to5mac.com/2014/01/11/how-to-use-apple-mail-rules-to-automatically-filter-out-unwanted-messages/) and [here](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-set-up-apple-mail-rules-2260876) to verify and double check that the rules are properly setup.

Comment: This solution does not work. Even after sorting, it still picks a random message. Remember, the script is being triggered by a mail rule on an incoming transaction. We're expecting to see the message selected by the rule, but getting a different message,

Comment: Could you make a print screen of the rule, because it appear that the rule condition is not properly setup ?

Comment: Image added to original post.

Comment: Write it in one line like it's supposed to be!: `tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Date" of menu "Sort By" of menu item "Sort By" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of process "Mail"`

Comment: Indentation may help sometimes, but I change according to your advice. @user3439894, have you any idea why his filter is not working ?

Comment: Yes, indentation and judicious use of white space is very helpful when coding, however a single System Event to click a menu item in the manner you posted is IMO a poor way to code a single event such as that. If you want it not to be on one line, you can break it down as in this example https://paste.ee/p/kfKkN , either way is better then how originally posted. That said, to answer the question in your comment... Since I'm not in a position to test the OP's code in Mail, I really can't effectively troubleshoot the issue. Although, for a +100 bonus I really wish I could test it.

Comment: To clarify what I have done, I sorted the mail list manually in the app. I did not try sorting using the script, since it would be redundant.

Comment: Can you try to add the condition rules : "Status | is Unread" and remove the action "stop evaluating rules", and add an action to "move email to a folder", to avoid your filter to treat indefinitely the same email and then stop.

Comment: Mail.app does not have the option to check mail status as unread. Your other suggestions made no difference.